# Как получить группу изображений от пользователя в aiogram

Tags: python, sqlite3, aiogram

Я пытась разобраться telegram ботах. Мне нужно собрать информацию от пользователя и отправить в SQLite и я уже нагуглил  про состояния. Код просит пользователя ввести данные и вроде это работает, но когда приходит группа изображения я могу получить только одну.
Разбирая message, я нашел media_group_id и продпологаю, что там где-то можно достать все изображения, но не понимаю как.
Где рыть?

````
# @dp.message_handler(commands=["newItem"], state='*')
async def newItem_handler(message):
    await message.answer("Title")
    await FSMGNI.NewItem.getTitle.set()


# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMGNI.NewItem.getTitle)
async def title_handler(message, state:FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(title=message.text)
    await FSMGNI.NewItem.next()
    await message.answer("Image")


# @dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"], state=FSMGNI.NewItem.getImage)
async def image_handler(message, state:FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(image=message.photo[-1].file_id)
    await FSMGNI.NewItem.next()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Для супер новичков(типо меня) оставлю свое решение. Мне хватило мозгов только на такой не очень интересный вариант:

```
n_image = 0 # Счетчик изображения (просто для имени изображения)

# Вход в FSM
# @dp.message_handler(commands=["newItem"], state='*')
async def newItem_handler(message):
    await message.answer("Title")
    await FSMGNI.NewItem.getTitle.set()


# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMGNI.NewItem.getTitle)
async def title_handler(message, state:FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(title=message.text)
#Добавил кнопку(ловлю изображения пока не нажму кнопку)
    await message.answer("Image", reply_markup=admin_newItem_button_next())
    await FSMGNI.NewItem.next()
    
# Ловлю избражения 
# @dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo", "text"], state=FSMGNI.NewItem.getImage)
async def image_handler(message, state:FSMContext):
    global n_image 

    if message.photo == []:
        n_image = 0
        await message.answer("Price: ")
        await FSMGNI.NewItem.next()    
    else:       
        data = await state.get_data()
        n_image += 1
        image_path = f"./images/{data['title']}{n_image}.jpg"
        await message.photo[-1].download(destination_file=image_path)
```

Comment: ```@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def photo_handler(userMessage):
    photo = userMessage.photo.pop()
    await photo.download(str(randint(1, 999))+'.png')```